# PowerShell appears to ignore node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to run a node server locally in PowerShell, which I am running as administrator on Windows 10. I have Node and NPM installed and I can run a dummy server: 
[image: PowerShell]
But when I try to run my server, it seems like it's ignoring my command. It doesn't give me any error or stacktrace, it just starts a new line. CMD gets the same result. I haven't been able to find anything about this.

Comment: Please share the code to `server.js` - we can't help you otherwise. If node works with other files, there's a 99% chance you have code where your process just exits normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was trying to test code locally that usually runs on a server. I had disabled HTTPS, but forgotten to add another server

```
var server = app.listen(APP_PORT, function() {
    console.log("Express server listening on port " + APP_PORT);
});
```